# Get The Json File of A dynamic Tilemap (Phaser.js)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I Have a tilemap thats Dynamically edited, With tiles added and removed, Along with two tilemap layers, Is there any method in phaser.js, with which i could download the tilemap as a file?

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-Box **not** that I know of, but you could iterate through all layers and tiles, and generate the `json` yourself.

Iterating over each **layer** of the **map** property `layers` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html#layers__anchor)), and over each **layer** with the function `forEachTile` ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.TilemapLayer.html#forEachTile__anchor)), but that is much work to generate it and depending on the map-size, take a long time.

> ***Probablly better:** you could make any map changes, also on a copy of the `json` in memory, and on download just offer the changed `json` file as download.*